# How do I open the jquery datepicker by clicking on a hyperlink?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a link `<a href="#">Choose Date</a>` that I want to click and pop open the datepicker. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: may be i misunderstood it. can you explain more what exactly you want, i gave one answer but i think you know that already

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, by calling it on a div](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline) and then showing/hiding that div. Use [altField](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altField) to write the date to a hidden input element.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this right. you can have a click handler for a href and handle the code inside that

```
<a href="#" class="sample">Choose Date</a>

$('.sample').click(function() {
   // write your logic here 
   return false;
});
```