# How can I toggle a calendar or datepicker in an overlay when clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm trying to attach the jQuery [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) to a hyperlink vs the conventional `input` element. I know this has already been talked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082204/how-to-display-jquery-datepicker-on-link-click) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419308/how-do-i-open-the-jquery-datepicker-by-clicking-on-a-hyperlink) which led me to this implementation:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var picker_link_id = "datepicker_link"
  var picker_div_id  = "datepicker"

  var picker_div = $("#" + picker_div_id)

  // initialize the datepicker
  picker_div.datepicker({
    onSelect: 
      function(dateText, picker) {
        picker_div.hide();
        // custom work
      }

  });

  // position & toggle the datepicker on link click
  $("#" + picker_link_id).click(function() {
    var $this = $(this)

    // position the datepicker
    picker_div.css('position', 'absolute');
    picker_div.css('left', $this.position().left - (picker_div.width() - $this.width()));

    picker_div.toggle()

    return false;
  });

  // pressing ESC or clicking outside the datepicker should close it
  $(document)
    .bind("keypress", function(e) {
      if ( e.keyCode == 27 )
        picker_div.hide();
    })
    .bind("mousedown", function(e) {
      if ( e.target.id == $("#" + picker_link_id)[0].id )
        return;

        if ( e.target.id != picker_div_id  && $(e.target).parents('#' + picker_div_id).length == 0 )
            picker_div.hide();
    });
});
```

In my view, I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="datepicker_link">September 26, 2011</a>             
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Even though the above works, it seems like I'm re-creating some jQuery logic. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't get why you want to position the datepicker upon clicking on the anchor...can't you simply keep the `picker_div.toggle()` statement?

Comment: @WilliamNiu, I position `picker_div` to give it the 'overlay' feel. If I just toggle then it when the datepicker becomes visible and pushes other elements out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use an `input` element, instead of a `div` one, and position the input element out of the sight of the screen. Then you will be able to make use of the `.datepicker('show')` and `.datepicker('hide')`.

Then you can position the datepicker div with a css rule, such as the following one:

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
    top: 50px !important;
    left: 50px !important;
}
```

Note the `!important` keyword needs to be used, to effectively override the dynamic position.

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/william/VCQsk/.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
```

Comment: This was one of the first things I tried but it doesn't seem to work when the datepicker is attached to a div. I'll try again for sanity though...